# select is not picking value in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am making a select dropdown in a loop and putting the selected value in the form hidden attribute. It is working correctly for the first time but on reloading of the same page, it always sets 0 for that attribute.
Here is my code. It seems to be simple but I am unable to understand where I am going wrong.

```
<?php 
                  $dex=0;
                  if($row!=''){
                    foreach($teacher as $value){
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $value['first_name'].' '.$value['last_name'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row[$dex]['subject_name'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php //echo $value['father_name'] ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-label-group">
                            <select id="exam_term" class="form-control" name="exam_term" >
                                    <option value="0">Assesment</option>
                                    <option value="1">First</option>
                                    <option value="2">Second </option>
                                    <option value="3">Mid Term </option>
                                    <option value="4">Prelium </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/teacher/view_subject_marks">
                            <input type="hidden" name="exam_id" value=""/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="teacher_id" value="<?php echo $value['id'] ?>"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="class_id" value="<?php echo $row[$dex]['class_id'] ?>"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="subject_id" value="<?php echo $row[$dex]['subject_id'] ?>"/>
                            <input  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm submit_btn" type="submit" value="View Marks" />
                        </form>  
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                      <?php 
                        $dex++;
                    }
                  }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
```

and here is my jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('select').change(function(){
            var exam_term = $('#exam_term option:selected').val();
            alert(exam_term);
            $('input[name=exam_id]').val(exam_term)  ;  


        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why not make the select part of the form?

Comment: Oh great thanks did it

Answer (score 0):

Work with ids and it can be shortened.

```
<input type="hidden" name="exam_id" id="exam_id" value=""/> 

$(document).ready(function(){
        $('select').change(function(){
            $('#exam_id').val($('#exam_term).val())  ;  
        });
});
```